# How to get rid of 422 error in Jmeter.

Tags: jmeter

I have a JSON call. when i send that call through Jmeter HTTP Request, gets 422 Uprocessable entity. Anyone face this issue. How to fixed this error. Proper step would be very helpfull.

Help would really appreciate!!!

Answer (score 2):

As per [422 - Unprocessable Entity](http://www.restpatterns.org/HTTP_Status_Codes/422_-_Unprocessable_Entity) page

> The 422 (Unprocessable Entity) status code means the server understands the content type of the request entity (hence a 415(Unsupported Media Type) status code is inappropriate), and the syntax of the request entity is correct (thus a 400 (Bad Request) status code is inappropriate) but was unable to process the contained instructions. For example, this error condition may occur if an XML request body contains well-formed (i.e., syntactically correct), but semantically erroneous, XML instructions.

The problem is in the **body** of your request. You have correct content-type header, use correct method, send well-formed JSON or XML but one of the parameters is missing or incorrect.

1. Use [View Results Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener to inspect request and response details. Pay attention to Response Data tab, well-behaved server should provide a message regarding what's went wrong
2. Use [Debug Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Debug_Sampler) to test JMeter Variables values
3. Check *jmeter.log* file for any suspicious entries

You might also want to try out the brand new [Step-by-Step Debugger for JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/step-step-debugger-jmeter-it%E2%80%99s-not-dream-anymore)

Comment: Hi,maybe too late, but we here have an app that MUST return 422 for an anonymous request to a certain API, how to make JMeter to not display the result of that request as an error? In fact I expect OP's question to be about the same.

Comment: You can "expect" status code 422 by adding a [Response Assertion](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/response-assertions-in-jmeter-32-new-and-improved) configured like: 1. Tick `Ignore Status` box, set "Field to test" to `Response Code`, set "Pattern matching Rules" to `Equals`, add `422` as the "Pattern to test".

Comment: Nice, I just came up with the same solution by fiddling with response assertion element. :)

Answer (score 0):

In case you are placing a POST HTTP request and uploading any file, add the Parameter name and MIME type of the uploading file. And also make sure you're setting the multipart/form-data (if it is).